# how to make Jquery ui datepicker range

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have two input fields for start and end date and I need if the user select start date make just 14 days available to select in end date how can I do that?

here my html code:

```
                <label for="start_date">Date From</label>
                <input id="start_date" required="true" width="276"/>


                <label for="end_date">Date To</label>
                <input id="end_date" required="true" width="276"/>
```

and here my script:

```
        <script>
            $('#start_date').datepicker({
                uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4'
            });
        </script>
        <script>
            $('#end_date').datepicker({
                uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
                numberOfMonths: 2

            });
        </script>
```

Comment: so you want to limit the second date picker

Comment: exactly , but i need to limit that based on start date picker

Comment: wait, I figured out your problem.

Comment: answered. Simple use max and min dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `max-date` and `min-date` for this.

```js
$("#start_date").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var olddate = new Date($(this).val());
        var newdate = new Date();
        var numberOfDaysToAdd = 14;
        newdate.setDate(olddate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);           
        $("#end_date").datepicker({
          minDate: olddate,
          maxDate: newdate
        });       
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/jquery.daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<label for="start_date">Date From</label>
<input id="start_date" required="true" width="276"/>


<label for="end_date">Date To</label>
<input id="end_date" required="true" width="276"/>
```